# box show alert but i want other method like using of if chain or switch or using of for loop or using of map operator

Tags: javascript, html

When you run my code and click all the three boxes you get some alert for each boxes but i want any alternation code for alert like in my code i used three time query selector but i want to know without using three times query selector but only one time for all boxes and inside eventlistener using of like if chain or loop for to show alert of boxes when we click

I use query selector 3 times that show below if there is any alternation by using if chain or loop for alert of coloured boxes

```js
function hi() { //here is using of queryselector but i want this by using of if chain or loop that can show alertness for colored box

  document.querySelector('.green').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(`hi i'm a green`)
  })
  document.querySelector('.blue').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(`hi i'm a blue`)
  })
  document.querySelector('.orange').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(`hi i'm a orange`)
  })

}

hi()
```

```css
.box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding-top: 0.6%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>I'm iron man</h1>
<div class="box green">I'm a green</div>
<div class="box blue">I'm a blue</div>
<div class="box orange">I'm a orange</div>
```

Comment: It's a little tough to figure out what you want to accomplish here, could you provide some more details as to what you're trying to change/fix/accomplish?

Comment: when you run my code and click all the three boxes you get some alert for each boxes but i want any alternation code for alert like in my code i used three time query selector but i want to know without using three times query selector  but only one time for all boxes and inside eventlistener using of like if chain or loop for to show alert of boxes when we click

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this, let me know if this isn't what you're looking for an I'll edit my answer accordingly:

```js
function hi() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            alert(`hi i'm a ${e.target.className.replace('box', '').trim()}`)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach.call` does not seem to be necessary in modern browsers

Comment: @mplungjan Yea I felt pretty dirty writing that, I changed it to cast the HTML collection to an array and performed a forEach on that. Still feels less than optimal though, can you suggest a more efficient/cleaner way?

Comment: I like `[...document.querySelectorAll(".box")].forEach`

Comment: Or without the [...] - only IE needs it

Comment: @mplungjan Yup that's a much nicer looking solution, I've edited it to include that!

Comment: I think you do not need to convert it to array. ```.forEach``` will work on **nodeList**, but if you really want to convert this to array just use: ```Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('selector'))```

Comment: @Kanow Correct, initially I was using `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns an HTMLCollection (where array methods can't be applied), but after switching to `document.querySelectorAll`, it returns the NodeList where array methods can be used (and therefore would make the cast to Array redundant)

Comment: @Kanow - ie needs conversion to array. Othe browsers can use forEach directly

Comment: **IE** xD I think it is [not even a browser](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/)

Comment: but yep you are right it will not work on **IE** then you can use ```Array.from()```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class `box` to each div and **id** with div color then you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.box')` and then iterate over this array. Inside this iteration you can check the id of **div** and display allert basing on **div id**

Example:

**HTML**

```html
<h1>I'm iron man</h1>
<div id="green" class="box">I'm a green</div>
<div id="blue" class="box">I'm a blue</div>
<div id="orange" class="box">I'm a orange</div>
```

**JS**

```js
function hi() {
  const colorBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  colorBoxes.forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener('click', () => {
     if (box.id === 'green') {
      alert(`hi i'm a green`);
     } else if (box.id === 'blue') {
      alert(`hi i'm a blue`);
     } else {
      alert(`hi i'm a orange`);
     }
    })
  });
}
```